# Identify forwarded calls

Tags: twilio

I'm very new at using Twilio. I just created my first flow using Studio, which forwards SMS and calls to my personal phone. Is there a way to differentiate forwarded inbound calls (business) from regular direct calls (personal)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I would edit the caller ID in the `Connect Call To` widget in Studio to be a different validated outgoing number so you know if it is that number, it is for business, as mentioned in [this tutorial on call-forwarding with Studio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/tutorials/how-to-forward-calls).

You could also trigger the sending of a SMS message from Studio before forwarding the call or SMS message saying that the incoming message/call is for business.

We also offer the [Lookup API in your console](https://www.twilio.com/console/lookup) to find information like location, caller name, and carrier.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you set caller IDs as strings? I didn't know that! How is that done?